# MongoDB GeoNear Aggregation Result Size Limits

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using MongoDB 2.6.3 to query against a large collection of geospatial data. Specifically, I'm looking at querying the dataset for all pings within a few kilometers of a central location, and then collapsing them by user identifier to get a count of how many pings each user has.

Naturally, I'm using MongoDB aggregation for this, and specifically the $geoNear pipeline stage. However, it looks like, even though aggregation returns a cursor in 2.6.0, the $geoNear still has restrictions on the size of the result set tied to when aggregation returned a document. Namely, aggregation with $geoNear is returning only 65,000 records, while an equivalent (cursored) query is returning 200,000+.

Does anyone have any insight as to how I can perform large-scale aggregation then with geoNear?

edit:
Sample document:

```
{
"initial_epoch_time" : 1370062800,
"location" : [
    -72.3458073902,
    41.8241332683
],
"_id" : ObjectId("540a34050dc2520000912286"),
"__v" : 0
}
```

The following cursored query returns a count of ~200,000 documents, which I suspect is the correct number:

```
 var cursor = db.pings.find( { location : { $near: { $geometry: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [-71.10560939999999, 42.3465666] }, $maxDistance: 10*1000 } } } )
 var ctr = 0; 
 while(cursor.hasNext()) 
 { ctr++; 
  var ping = cursor.next()
 } 
 print(ctr)
```

while the following aggregation-based query:

```
 var cursor = db.pings.aggregate ( [ {$geoNear: { near: {type: "Point", coordinates:     [-71.10560939999999, 42.3465666]},limit: 100000000, spherical: true, maxDistance: 10*1000, distanceField: "distance"} } ] )
 var ctr = 0; 
 while(cursor.hasNext()) 
 { ctr++; 
  var ping = cursor.next()
 } 
 print(ctr)
```

returns ~65,000 documents, regardless of maxDistance.

Comment: I'm not aware of any limitation like this. Can you show us the aggregation and the "equivalent" cursored query? A sample socument would be helpful, too.

Comment: Interesting. Do the results change for the aggregation form if you specify a legacy coordinate pair in the query rather than GeoJSON? In the same way does converting maxDistance to radians return a correct result? Noting that your data is legacy co-ordinates here so radians might be returned. Check the values in the projected "distance" field and see if it looks like meters between the data and query points. If not then it is radians and not the same in both queries.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that `location` in the original document is given as legacy coordinate pairs while the query and the aggregation use GeoJSON. Another note is that the query uses a planar query, whereas the aggregations matches spherical.

Comment: I agree with Neil and Markus. It looks like the problem is a unit mismatch between using legacy pairs vs geoJSON, radians vs meters. Try being consistent with legacy pairs and using radians and see if the delta between the count remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$geoNear as an command has a 16MB document limit to the output. I've found out that you won't retrieve any errors but the document will be automatically cut to the aggregation's document size limit. You can test by reducing size of your documents in the collection. You will get more results when you make your collection's documents smaller.

Line 235:
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/commands/geo_near_cmd.cpp

Comment: For anyone else seeing this issue, the 16MB limit is fixed in MongoDB 4.2 (not yet released at the time of this comment). [See SERVER-18965 on MongoDB's Jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-18965)